# Heroku deployment failed when installing an add-on

Tags: python, postgresql, github, heroku, add-on

When I try to deploy an heroku app it gives:

An error was encountered when contacting the add-on partner to create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev: Available versions are 9.6, 10, 11, 12 (the default is 12)

Answer (score 0):

https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/app-json-schema#addons

Probably your add-on version is 9.5. You need to change it in `app.json` to one of: 9.6, 10, 11, 12.